# Is it possible to configure Outlook 365 views?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I'm wondering if it is possible to configure Outlook 365's navigation views (tabs?). I would like to have my inbox, todays calendar and tasks in one view. I don't think it is possible, but maybe I'm missing something? 
Outlooks' UI looks and feels very dated. I'm surprised MS hasn't addressed this yet, using dashboard and tiles.

/Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can use the To-Do bar to display your upcoming calendar events, your task list, or your favorite contacts.

Reference: [Use and customize the To-Do bar](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-and-customize-the-to-do-bar-4b6c5bb4-88a0-46c2-9159-6d0a0133ff79)

From the reply of Steve Fan in this [TechNet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2f155f5b-784d-4d3c-9cfa-bd6c7b676c87/outlook-2013-to-do-bar-not-show-all-appointments?forum=outlook),the To-Do Bar calendar will show upcoming appointments/meetings in the next 7 days.